# Integrate Sandisk Connect Wireless Stick in ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, storage, wireless

I want to connect the **Sandisk Connect Wireless stick** in ios app via Bluetooth or wifi and fetch all files from that storage device in my ios app. As I have done much research regarding this, but I am unable to find any single code for connecting a wireless storage device in my ios app.

**Note**: Not important that I will use only Sandisk device. I just want to connect & fetch the files from the wireless storage device in my ios app

Comment: The Sandisk device uses WiFi, not Bluetooth.  Unless they provide an SDK or details on their device you would need to reverse engineer their protocol in order to write your own app to talk to it.  There is no general protocol that you could use to communicate with any such device

Comment: Can you please elaborate the comment. Also, I know that it works on the wireless. But I want to connect any storage device with Wifi or Bluetooth. So for that, I need some references regarding how it works as SanDisk works here

Comment: There is no standard. Generally each manufacturer would create their own protocols. You might find that wifi devices use a web interface; so you could communicate using HTTP

Comment: @RaviB, have you found a solution for this subject? I'm interesting on similar thing.

Comment: @jimpanzer Not yet.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to the device, use this information found on the Sandisk website: *https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17528/~/connecting-to-the-wireless-stick-using-ios-or-android-devices*

> 1. Plug the SanDisk Connect Wireless Stick into a computer or USB-AC adaptor to ensure that it’s fully charged. A full charge can take up to 2 hours.
> 2. Install the “SanDisk Connect” app from the App Store, if not already installed.
> 3. Turn on the Wireless Stick by pressing and releasing the power button
> 4. Connect to Wireless Stick Wi-Fi network “SanDisk Connect ######”
>         a. ###### will be a unique identifier for your specific unit.
>         b. iPhone, iPad or iPod touch: Connect to the Wireless Stick Wi-Fi network through the device settings
>              i. Click on the Settings icon
>              ii. Click on Wi-Fi
>              iii. Select “SanDisk Connect ######”
> 5. Launch the “SanDisk Connect” mobile app.

To transfer files through a browser, you can use the app or follow the below instructions that are also found on the Sandisk website: *https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17540/related/1*

> 1. Connect to the Wireless Stick Wi-Fi network “SanDisk Connect ######”
>        a. ###### will be a unique identifier for your specific unit.
> 2. Enter www.sandisk.com/myconnect in your web browser or IP address 172.25.63.1
> 3. You can now browse and download within the browser

This may or may not work in iOS with the current strict, but hopefully loosening situation for storing and downloading files onto the device.I hope this helps solve your problem. I don't have the wireless stick or an iOS device, so I can't verify. Sorry for that inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

So I am not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve programmatically in your app but depending on the use case there are two things you could look at.

**I want the user to add/view files in my app**

In this usage scenario, I would take a look at [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller). This is supported for iOS 8 and above I suspect will achieve a good deal of what you probably want excluding the specific hardware requirement. Do note that are significant capability differences between iOS versions for this ViewController, particularly iOS 11 with the introduction of the Files App.

**I have a hardware device/remote service that stores files and want the user to access**

In this usage scenario, I would take a look at [FileProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) framework and more importantly `NSFileProviderExtension` and `NSFileProviderManager`. This API is primarily for the use of applications that primarily manage files and user content. Do note again that with iOS 11 there were significant changes to file management with the introduction of the Files app.

If you're able to target iOS 13 and later, you probably don't need any of this if you're okay with users plugging a USB drive to their device. In that case, you can probably get away with the above.

As a final note, if Sandisk Connect does not integrate with FileProvider, which I personally cannot confirm as I do not own a device, then setting up `NSFileProviderExtension` and `NSFileProviderManager` probably won't help you all that much, unless you're willing to sit there and reverse-engineer any protection mechanisms they may or may not have implemented. Looking at reviews of the device, it does seem that stick is effectively a computer on a USB stick, which suggest Sandisk has done what @Paulw11 has suggested. If you're lucky, stick may be nothing more than a wireless router, web server and ftp server all rolled into one. You might need to spend some time in either your preferred web browsers console or Wireshark to see exactly how they're doing the communication and hoping it's not encrypted or obfuscated.